# python wand.image is not recognized

Tags: python-2.7, imagemagick, wand, magickwand

I installed Imagemagic (both 32 and 64 bits versions were tried) and then used pip to install wand, I also set the Magick_Home env. variable to imagemagic address but when I run

> `Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>     File "c:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\wand\image.py", line 20, in <module>
>       from .api import MagickPixelPacket, libc, libmagick, library
>     File "c:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\wand\api.py", line 205, in <module>
>       'Try to install:\n  ' + msg)
>   ImportError: MagickWand shared library not found.
>   You probably had not installed ImageMagick library.
>   Try to install:
>     http://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/guide/install.html#install-imagemagick-on-windows`

Comment: Which version of ImageMagick did you install?

Comment: ImageMagic 7.0.1-Q16 from its binary

Comment: Ah! You'll need 6.9.3-9

Comment: Forbidden Overseer's solution worked for me. Keep in mind that the oldest library is currently 6.9.7-10 (And will probably keep changing.) The location of imagemagick should be changed accordingly (...Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.7-10/lib...).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

ImageMagick Version 7 is a very recent major release. It'll take some time for the community behind [wand](/questions/tagged/wand) (and other bindings) to update core libraries.

For now, you'll have to install the last release of Version 6 ([ImageMagick-6.9.8-9-Q16-x64-dll.exe](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-6.9.8-9-Q16-x64-dll.exe)) from http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/

Comment: The link in the answer is outdated. Here is the link to the latest 6.x version as of `07/19/2016`:
[ImageMagick-6.9.5-2-Q16-x64-dll.exe](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-6.9.5-2-Q16-x64-dll.exe)
Thank you [emcconville](http://stackoverflow.com/users/438117/emcconville)

Comment: The commented link is also outdated. Any other source?

Comment: @majidarif - Navigate to the parent directory of the link(s) to view all latest binary builds. As of 08/17/2016 the version is [ImageMagick-6.9.5-7-Q16-x64-dll.exe](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-6.9.5-7-Q16-x64-dll.exe)

Comment: Yeah. I realized. Thanks.

Comment: @Tarocco Checkout the [C-API refactor branch](https://github.com/dahlia/wand/pull/347). Windows + IM7 has been build, but nobody has offered to help test it.

Answer (score 47):

For those on mac and using homebrew, it seems like Wand doesn't support imagemagick 7 yet as mentioned in other answers.

There's a [new brew formula for Imagemagick 6](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/8954) which can be used to install the older version in the meanwhile:

```
brew install imagemagick@6
```

Create a symlink to this newly installed dylib file as mentioned in other answer to get things working.

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/<your specific 6 version>/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.dylib /usr/local/lib/libMagickWand.dylib
```

Tested on Sierra and seems to be working fine.

Comment: This worked for me, but I didn't need the symlink - just `export MAGICK_HOME=/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6` in my shell config

Comment: @Greg, for some reason adding that to my `.profile` still doesn't work. I still need to export it right on my terminal every time. I'm using iterm2.

Comment: Forbidden Overseer solution works. Small tip: make sure you create the correct symbolic link. As in: don't assume you have the 6.9.8-4 version. In my case it was 6.9.9-5_1 version. Rookie mistake.

Comment: This is the right answer. Great job. It should be noted that Wand is (as of this writing) incompatible with ImageMagick 7, hence, you need to install imagemagick@6. Do a $brew search imagemagick to see the other version options available :)

Comment: This answer was the end of a one-hour search! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

For me on my Mac I had to (found Wand looks for MAGICK_HOME in Wand source):

```
export MAGICK_HOME="/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.9-31"
```

That was after installing version 6 of imagemagick. I took a look at the Python source for Wand that was installed after I ran `pip3 install Wand`. The scripts were looking for imagemagick 6 (I attempted to add 7 into the list of versions it looks for, but got a "wrong version" error).

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install imagemagick@6
```

Now, imagemagick version 6 is installed and Wand looks in `$MAGICK_HOME` for the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

For M1 macs, the path you want would be `export MAGICK_HOME="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.12-61"`

Answer (score -1):

I have found a solution.
The problem is:

Wand try to find a file like that: libMagickWand.dylib in /usr/local/lib/

But if you install ImageMagick with Homebrew, the file generated is libMagickWand-6.Q16.dylib
And Wand never find it.

So, you have 2 solutions:

1. Create a symbol link from libMagickWand-7.Q16.dylib to libMagickWand.dylib
2. You can install by MacPorts or from binaries testing that they create the file.

I have installed the ImageMagick for The Capitan from:
http://cactuslab.com/assets/installers/ImageMagick-6.9.1-0.pkg.zip
and I declare:

`export MAGICK_HOME=/opt/ImageMagick`