# Wand does not work under python 64 bit and imagemagick 64 bit: cannot find shared libraries

Tags: wand

I am running python 2.7 64bit on windows and have installed imagemagick 64 bit (latest version available) with the necessary headers and env variables as stated in the guide. Unfortunately I am able to install wand via pip but as soon as I try to use wand I get this error:

```
>>> from wand.image import Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wand\image.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .api import MagickPixelPacket, libc, libmagick, library
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wand\api.py", line 205, in <module>
    'Try to install:\n  ' + msg)
ImportError: MagickWand shared library not found.
You probably had not installed ImageMagick library.
Try to install:
  http://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/guide/install.html#install-imagemagick-on-wi
ndows
```

Has anyone experienced this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python wand.image is not recognized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011291/python-wand-image-is-not-recognized)

Comment: Duplicate, the issue has been solved, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install the version: [ImageMagick-6.9.8-9-Q16-x64-dll.exe](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-6.9.8-9-Q16-x64-dll.exe)

Wand doesn't support the latest version as of yet.

Comment: Thank you, I've been searching ImageMagick forums for couple of hours, this is the only answer that solved the problem