# Unable to get animated GIFs to work with Wagtail

Tags: wagtail, wand

I'm trying to get animated GIFs to work with Wagtail CMS. I've followed the [instructions](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/advanced_topics/images/animated_gifs.html) to install Wand (and the ImageMagick dependency) but Wagtail doesn't seem to recognize it and instead just converts GIFs to PNGs.

Is there a step I'm missing?

Comment: Just to note that once you install the correct versions of Wand an ImageMagic you MUST upload a new gif file to test.  If wagtail has already converted a gif to PNG, it will keep using the PNG file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have found this yet but it sounds like a similar issue:

https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/2505

I've just installed Wand 0.4.4 and "ImageMagick 6.9.3-6 Q16 x86_64 2016-02-28" (using brew) and been able to upload and view an animated gif. I have Wagtail 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

Wand currently doesn't work with Image Magick 7 so you have to install version 6.x. This is what I did to get it working on OSX Sierra:

```
brew install imagemagick@6
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.9-7/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.dylib /usr/local/lib/libMagickWand.dylib
```

You might need to change the version in the symbolic link target.

The solution is from this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41772062/628709).